# Unable to access to mlflow ui

Tags: python, python-3.x, mlflow

By following quickstart and tutorial at https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/quickstart.html, and https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/tutorial.html, the execution of train.py works fine.

```
Elasticnet model (alpha=0.500000, l1_ratio=0.500000):
  RMSE: 0.8222428497595403
  MAE: 0.6278761410160693
  R2: 0.12678721972772622
```

But when launching the ui `mlflow ui`, and accessing to the web page localhost:5000, the browser complains

```
Not Found

The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

What went wrong and how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of mlflow are you using? What's the output of the following command? : mlflow --version

Comment: Sorry I can't remember now because I've removed it temporarily. It seems that if I execute it on the path where mlrun exists, this message pops out when accessing to mlflow entrypoint url. However, executing mlfow ui on the parent folder first (which would gets empty mlrun created) then go back to mlrun folder where experiments get created. Then this error goes away. But I can't check that now as I've work on other task. May go back to see if this issue still persists. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

There's many different issues that may or may not be happening. You're best bet is to plain-old troubleshoot. I saw you're comment on GitHub, so let's try a new angle; it's more than likely a building/debugging file path or directory setting which is incorrect.

I noticed a file/directory setting named `set_tracking_uri`.

```
def get_tracking_uri():
    """
    Returns the current tracking URI. Note that this may not correspond to the tracking URI of
    the currently active run, since the tracking URI may be updated via `set_tracking_uri`.
    :return: the tracking URI
    """
```

[`mlflow/tracking/__init__.py` - lines 52-56](https://github.com/databricks/mlflow/blob/32b3d6c2bee5c5337090b45778fb831280666363/mlflow/tracking/__init__.py#L51)

You could also check out the `package.json` for the server file path.

```
 "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "homepage": "/static-files",
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx}",
      "!**/*.test.{js,jsx}",
      "!**/__tests__/*.{js,jsx}"
    ]
```

[`mlflow/mlflow/server/js/package.json` - lines 37-44](https://github.com/databricks/mlflow/blob/1a1038ceb5a1673dda9c37b7ac763318e0446836/mlflow/server/js/package.json#L37)

Make sure your files are in the correct directory compared to your settings and I'm sure it will resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't check it now because being tight up with other tasks. Will come back review if this issue still persist or not. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Experienced the same issue, resolved by running `mlflow ui` from the examples folder as mentioned here [Github](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/108#issuecomment-410524808)

Comment: Also, the `train.py`  needs to be run from within the `examples` folder as the UI looks for runs in the `mlruns` folder in the directory that the UI was launched from and since `train.py` creates the `mlruns` folder in the directory that it was run from.

Answer (score 1):

Inside docker container, adding the `--host 0.0.0.0` solved my issue. Using mlflow 1.17.0

```
mlflow ui --host 0.0.0.0
```

https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/109#issuecomment-404146077

Comment: This solved my problem, although my problem was not related to OP's question.